# How to change the attribute values of the feature using the custom feature form

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qt

When i am using the following command it opens the feature form with all the fields:

```
qgis.utils.iface.openFeatureForm(qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer(), f)
```

But i want to open a feature form with the specified field names. How can i do that using python programming.

Comment: "... with the specified field names." Specified where?

Comment: I am adding the new field names to the vector layer so I want to open the form with the newly added field names  but not all the existing field names